# List replacing all the previous elements

Tags: c#, list, bitmap

Well I am working with C# for the first time and the problem in the title occurred. It's similar to other problems in stackoverflow however I am using the fix suggested by their answers and still doesn't work.

I want to save the first 50 frames of a video and I am doing this (the _frame_nr incrementation and the cycle are outside of this but they aren't related to the problem since that part works)

```
  if (_frame_nr < 50){
    Bitmap _curr_frame = new Bitmap(_width, _height, _stride, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, (IntPtr)curr_frame);
    _curr_frame.Save("C:\\curr_frame\\frame_nr_" + _frame_nr + ".png");
    prevFrames.Add(_curr_frame); }
```

This code works since the first 50 correct frames are being saved in the folder.

However Immediately after that I do this cycle

```
for (int y = 0; y < 50; y++)
{
    Bitmap _prev_frame = prevFrames[y];
    _prev_frame.Save("C:\\_prev_frame\\frame_nr_" + y + ".png");
}
```

And all the frames are being replace by the last one.

Now I know that doing add in a list add a reference instead of copying, but all the suggestions I checked say that by creating a new instance of the object inside for each element would make it reference each different one. So I don't know what I did wrong, maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder, is curr_frame being updated or overwritten with the image data for each frame?  It's possible that if you've just updating it then all instances of the Bitmap will point to the same image data instance...not a problem when saving as the image data will always be the frame you want to save but when you reference the object again later they'll all point to the same image data.

Comment: But by creating a new instance of the object each time wouldn't that avoid the problem?

Comment: @user697110 - you're create a new Bitmap object each time but I suspect each one is pointing to the same image data.  In the constructor to the bitmap you're passing (IntPtr)curr_frame, if that data is updated every Bitmap which points to it will also be updated.  Can you add the code when your set the value of curr_frame?

Comment: I can't because to be honest I can't find it myself since I am working on a code given to me and I mean to ask the person wrote it. I can say thought that it's indeed correctly iterating through the several frames of the video in this method.

Comment: @user697110 - I agree that it'll be correctly iterating through so when you save you'll get what you expect but if they're all pointing to the same curr_frame object the data they reference will be updated after the save.  Without seeing what sets curr_frame I doubt anyone will be able to help much more.  It might be worth doing a find in the code to see if you can spot where it is updated.

Comment: @ DoctorMick - The weird thing is that if I save that pointer into another one like this: _prev_frame = _curr_frame;
                _curr_frame = new Bitmap(...);                            The pointer is _prev_frame remains the old one and isn't updated, I would assume the same thing should have happened in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try cloning the bitmap when adding it to the List: prevFrames.Add(_curr_frame.Clone());

Comment: Tried, same issue happens